# DI container - cannot really see the benefit

Tags: dependency-injection

I am trying to understand some code where a DI container is used...it's a very basic implementation of a DI container which just maintains a `ConcurrentHashMap` with interfaces and the corresponding implementations/instances.

Also, the container is completely static.

In the application initialization (which is called with every HTTP request), views are registered in the Container:

```
Container.register(IHomeView.class, new HomeView());
```

And injected into the presenters:

```
HomePresenter(new Model(), Container.resolve(IHomeView.class));
```

I do not really see what the benefit of the container is. Can't one just instantiate a new `HomeView` and pass it to the Presenter via Constructor-injection?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two practical applications for using that container.

1. Project parallelism

If a different project team is working on the HomeView class, and it isn't quite ready, the project team that is writing the HomePresenter and the code that calls it can substitute a mock HomeView class by changing the container registration.

2. Unit testing

If you wish to isolate and unit test a section of code that excludes the HomeView class (e.g. if you want to mock the HomeView class) then you would change the container registration as part of setting up the test.